# Doesn't `odoc` show default function arguments?

Tags: ocaml

Say I have the following function signature:

```ml
let rec eval ?(env : environment = []) (t : term) : value =
  match t with
  | TVar idx -> List.nth env idx
  | TLam body -> VClosure (env, body)
  | TAppl (m, n) ->
    let rator = eval ~env m in
    let rand = eval ~env n in
    (match rator with
     | VClosure (env', body) -> eval ~env:(rand :: env') body
     | VNeutral neutral -> VNeutral (NAppl (neutral, rand)))
;;
```

In the documentation, which I build using `dune build @doc`, I want the default value for `env`, namely `[]`, to be publicly visible, since it's a part of the signature. However, the actual generated documentation is:

```
val eval : ?env:environment -> term -> value
```

Can `odoc` show default function arguments via some command-line option?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `odoc`, but that's a non-trivial task, since it would require actually printing *any* OCaml value. Only the toplevel can do that, with some cheats, and even then it's not perfect (some values just *can't* be rendered, such as function, but many more exist).

Comment: Well, I just assumed that it'd print a default value as specified in the text file. Now I have to write down the default value in the documentation, though probably it's not a big deal.

Comment: well, in your case the default value is just a value, but in general it might be a more complex expression or even a private variable otherwise undocumented.

Comment: Default values aren't part of the signature. They're an implementation detail, and therefore odoc would have to not just read the interface files, but also the implementation files. And then, as already pointed out, be able to print arbitrary values.

Comment: @glennsl That would make a good answer.